# What needs to be fixed with this custom alert template?

Tags: 2007, alert, custom-alert-templates

I've customized alert notification template for `Announcements` list. Here is custom code:

```
<Immediate>
    <Subject>
      <Switch>
        <Expr>
            <GetVar Name="EventType" />
        </Expr>
        <Case Value = "1">
            <HTML>New Content on Latest Events</HTML>
        </Case>
        <Case Value = "2">
            <HTML>Modified Content on Latest Events</HTML>
        </Case>
        <Case Value = "4">
            <HTML>Deleted Content on Latest Events</HTML>       
        </Case>
        <Default>
            <GetVar Name="AlertTitle" />
            <HTML><![CDATA[ - ]]></HTML><GetVar Name="ItemName" />
        </Default>
      </Switch>
    </Subject>
        <Fields>
          <Switch>
            <Expr>
              <GetVar Name="EventType" />
            </Expr>
            <Case Value = "1">
                <HTML>
                    <![CDATA[A new content has been added to Latest Events. 
                        To view, please visit: <a href="]]>
                </HTML>
                <GetVar Name="ItemUrl" URLEncodeAsURL="TRUE" />
                <HTML><![CDATA[">]]></HTML>
                <GetVar Name = "ItemName" />
                <HTML><![CDATA[</a><br/>Thank You<br/>]]></HTML>
            </Case>
            <Case Value = "2">
                <HTML>
                    <![CDATA[A content has been modified in Latest Events. 
                    To view, please visit: <a href="]]>
                </HTML>
                <GetVar Name="ItemUrl" URLEncodeAsURL="TRUE" />
                <HTML><![CDATA[">]]></HTML>
                <GetVar Name="ItemName" />
                <HTML><![CDATA[</a><br/>Thank You<br/>]]></HTML>
            </Case>
            <Case Value="4">
                <HTML>
                    <![CDATA[A content has been removed from Latest Events.
                    <br/>Thank You]]>
                </HTML>
            </Case>
            <Default>
              <GetVar Name="DisplayName#{Field}" HTMLEncode="TRUE" />
                <HTML><![CDATA[ : ]]></HTML>
              <GetVar Name="NewValue#{Field}" />            
            </Default>
          </Switch>
        </Fields>
        <Footer>
            <HTML><![CDATA[<br/><hr/>]]></HTML>
            $ResourcesNoEncode:Alerts_event_lastmodified;
        </Footer>
</Immediate>
```

The problems I'm facing are following:

1. <strike>The subject contains all the values irrespective of the type of event (1,2,4)</strike>  there was no `<Switch>` statement after `<Subject>`
2. The Item Added message is (in Fields -> Switch -> Case Value="1") is repeated thrice

Is something wrong with above template that is prompting SharePoint to behave wrongly or do I need to do some more work?

Comment: please somebody with sufficient points added `custom-alerts` or `custom-alert-templates` tags

Answer (score 1):

Is the added message repeated three times in one template, or are you getting three seperate templates created?  Perhaps you have more than one item in your Announcement list that is calling the new template multiple times.